# LINQ Set Operations not working (Intersect, Except)

Tags: c#, linq, intersection

I'd like to use the Uber-Coolness of LINQ set operations to express the following :

```
        foreach (Group group in groups)
        {
            if (user.Groups.Contains(group))
            {
                assignedGroups.Add(group);
            }
            else
            {
                availableGroups.Add(group);
            }
        }
```

I thought it should be a two-liner achieving this :

```
var assigned = user.Groups.Intersect(groups);
var available = groups.Except(user.Groups);
```

Whenever I run this example the foreach approach fills my lists correctly, while the set operations result in an empty assigned list and a filled available list. 
I thought it must be a problem concerning the equality check, but the fact that **Contains()** is working proves this wrong.
Can anyone help me see my misconception here?

the IEnumerable **groups** is also result of a LINQ query, just in case that information is of some help...

Comment: Is `Contains` your own method, or provided?

Comment: provided, no personal flavour here

Comment: for the intersection it doesn't make a difference, for the Exclusion I haven't tried, since that wouldn't make any sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it *shouldn't* make a difference, but from the point of view of symmetry I'd reverse how you're creating `assigned`. I'd also make sure that the query is only executed once, and that the remaining operations occur in-process:

```
var cachedGroups = groups.ToList();
var assigned = cachedGroups.Intersect(user.Groups);
var available = cachedGroups.Except(user.Groups);
```

One possibility is that `user.Groups` has a custom equality comparer. That *would* explain why the foreach version worked but the LINQ version didn't. What's the type of `user.Groups`, and how much do you know about the equality comparer it's using?

Comment: user.Groups is a custom type based on the BindingList<T> class. I can't follow you to why the Equality comparator of the list would make a difference (doesn't comparison happen element by element?), but I can tell for sure that <T> has a custom one.

Comment: sorry, mistaken there: user.Groups is an ObservableCollection<Group>. The rest is valid as said before

Comment: @Sebastian: If `user.Groups` has a custom equality comparer, then it might give a different answer in `Contains` than the default comparer used by Intersect and Except.

Comment: To get this right, Jon, do you refer to the collection's comparer or to the element's comparer?

Comment: @Sebastian: I'm talking about the comparer the *collection* uses to compare *elements*. For example, you can create a `HashSet<string>` with a case-insensitive equality comparer: `new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`.

Comment: OK, got it. The code does not specify Comparer Options, so I guess the ObservableCollection should use the default one, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Sebastian: Contains uses Equality comparison only, while Intersect and Except use GetHashCode also. If Hashing and comparison are not consistent you might get different behaviour for Contains and Intersect/Except.

Comment: Thanks, Konstantin, that solved the problem! I had to be consistent and override GetHashCode in my Group class (up to now, I had only overridden Equals)

Comment: @Konstantin: Contains *might* only use equality. Or it might use a hashcode as well. It depends on how the collection is implemented. For example, `HashSet` would definitely use the hash code. I don't know about ObservableCollection... but it's a good point and worth looking into. A broken GetHashCode method could explain this.

Comment: @Sebastian: I'm glad that's fixed it - but if you overrode Equals without overriding GetHashCode, I would have expected the compiler to give you a warning. Didn't it?

Comment: @Sebastian: Something like this: "Test.cs(3,14): warning CS0659: 'Test' overrides Object.Equals(object o) but does not override Object.GetHashCode()". Never ignore warnings like that!

Comment: @Jon: Surely, it can be implemented in different ways for different classes, but I've talked about this specific case only.