# Comparing two large lists and assigning property values from another

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, performance, list

I have a very simple method of comparing two lists and then assigning the value from first list to second like following:

```
private void FindUPC(List<ResultItem> filteredProducts, List<zsp_select_UserItems_Result> items)
    {
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            foreach (var trItem in filteredProducts)
            {
                if (item.ItemID == trItem.ID)
                {
                    trItem.UPC = item.UPC;
                    trItem.EAN = item.EAN;
                    trItem.MPN = item.MPN;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

However, when doing it like this on large collections such as let's say comparing collection where each list contains 50000 items inside, the execution time that it takes here is a whooping 30000 miliseconds (30 seconds)... This impacts the performance terribly, so I'm wondering what is the fastest way to compare two lists and then assign the values like I've shown in my previous example that I wrote?

Can someone help me out?

P.S. Guys can I use IEqualityComparer for this?

@Stephen did you mean something like this:

```
private void FindUPC(List<ResultItem> filteredProducts, List<zsp_select_UserItems_Result> items)
{
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        foreach (var trItem in filteredProducts)
        {
            if (item.ItemID == trItem.ID)
            {
                trItem.UPC = item.UPC;
                trItem.EAN = item.EAN;
                trItem.MPN = item.MPN;

            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Anyone guys? =) =)

Comment: Is your `trItem.ID` unique (you loop continues to execute even if the first item matches - so you could break out of the inner loop if it is unique)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I edited my question, was that what you ment? =)

Comment: No, I believe he meant break inside the if statement

Comment: Break inside the `if` block :)

Comment: Note an `IEqualityComparer` is not going to help if all you want to compare is the `ID` values

Comment: @StephenMuecke That got me whole 4 seconds of improvement xD Still whooping 26 seconds omg ... xD

Comment: Then you will need to use something with constant lookup time. A dictionary for instance.

Comment: @npearson could you show me an example ? =)

Comment: Not exactly sure what you trying to do, but one of Union/Intersect/Expect (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825736/linq-set-operations-not-working-intersect-except) may be what you want... At very least use Dictionary to do matching.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov it's simple, compare two lists with ID values, and if the ID values mathces with both items in list, assign value from first property to second property in second list, but im not sure why is it taking so much time to execute.. I thought everything runs quite fast in RAM ... =/

Comment: If both lists contain that many records, then you might need to rethink your algorithm, or actually rethink why you think you need this kind of comparison... I am not sure if your method name is correct either, it's function is really not `findUPC` it's something like `MutateFilteredProductsWithMachingUPC`. Shouldn't this be rather something that a db should do?

Comment: @Icepickle haha yes ur correct =) ... It's much more than just FindUPC XD

Comment: Is your list `filteredProducts` actually shared between more users, for me personally I think there is not enough information to give good recommendations, except that you should rethink why you want to have that many products in a list, and why you want to mutate it through a for loop

Comment: @Icepickle no it's not shared, it's a list of records that belongs to 1 user

Comment: And that user needs 50000 records per list at once? How can you make a meaningful representation of this logic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Load all your items into a data structure with constant lookup.  Then perform your loop.

```
private void FindUPC(List<ResultItem> filteredProducts, List<zsp_select_UserItems_Result> items)
{
    var itemsDict = items.ToDictionary(i => i.ItemID);
    
    foreach (var trItem in filteredProducts)
    {
        if (itemsDict.TryGetValue(trItem.ID, out var item)) {
            trItem.UPC = item.UPC;
            trItem.EAN = item.EAN;
            trItem.MPN = item.MPN;
        {
    }
}
```

Comment: It's showing me an error on "out var item"  , says it doesn't exists in current context?

Comment: it's a C# 7 feature, you need visual studio 2017

Comment: @User987, The syntax is for c# 6

Comment: @StephenMuecke It's really [C# 7](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/)

Comment: @npearson still getting this one: There is no argument that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'value' of dictionary<string,...>

Comment: @User987 Glad that helps!